# unity3d navmeshagent offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tower defense game in Unity using C# where NavMeshAgents (enemies) spawn and travel along this path to the end point, where they are destroyed. When I have many agents grouped together or traveling in one line overlapping each other, [the health bars form one long line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eL5B.png) I would like to make it so the NavMeshAgents have slight offsets that are kept across the whole map so the health bars don't align. Is there any relatively simply way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change [agent's "Radius"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshAgent.html) to a bigger number. Then make sure bar width is < agent's radius.

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work for me because I will want to have enemies extremely close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make this bar hidden by default. And only show it for enemies with health less than 100%. Problem solved/avoided?

Comment: How would that avoid the problem, though? Especially when I have 200 agents grouped together in a very tight space forming one line, no matter how thin the health bar is, it will still form a line.

Comment: Disable them entirely then. Sounds drastic but give it a thought.

Comment: Precision in health bars is crucial when it's displaying human player life in hardcore games like Dark Souls. For swarming mobs in tower defense - not exactly.

Comment: Other than disabling them you can think outside the box a little. This is UX for game hence there are more ways to communicate that to player.

For example:

**A)** enemies can go become tinted depending on health (becoming little darker or something similarly simple).

**B)** they can use 3 different graphics (or animations) to display their approximate health level (different one for 0-33%, 33-66% and 66-100%).

**C)** <maybe something even more creative> (but those above may prove to be just enough!).

I don't know, give it a try. Bars are not best way to do this necessarily.